# Tabbing p for html paragraph tag in VS Code results in get propertyName()

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, paragraph

I am using Visual Studio Code for writing HTML. Whenever I tab `p` for the paragraph tag, it gives me;

```
get propertyName() {
    return.this.;
}
```

instead of `<p></p>`. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post some extension you're using. This problem mostly because you using extension of VSC to quick render code

Comment: I disabled all the extensions and now the autocomplete is working fine. I will enable them one-by-one to see which extension is causing the problem.